# Regular Expressions with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I am trying to validate a string against the following regular expression:

```
[(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}]
```

1. The validation passes if it done using the `numberOfMatches` method as follows:

   ```
   NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@“[(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}]” options:0 error:&error];
   NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

   BOOL status numberOfMatches == string.length;
   ```
2. If the validation is done using a `NSPredicate` the validation fails:

   ```
   NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", [(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}]];
   BOOL status  = [test evaluateWithObject:string];
   ```

What's the reason for this? I would like to do this using a `NSPredicate`.

Comment: I am not an ObjC expert, but that does not seem like a valid regular expression in any language I am familiar with. What did you intend for it to match? Specifically, the square brackets surrounding the entire thing are likely not supposed to be there.

Comment: Do you want to validate if a string is alphanumeric or not? Where you want to use this regular expression?

Comment: Both attempts are incorrect. The regex should be `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$`. In the first case, `numberOfMatches` should be checked against 1. In the second case, you have to provide `@"'^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$'"` as argument.

Comment: Thanks guys , it did not occur to me the regex could be wrong , however the numberOfMataches becomes 6 if I use a string like "aaaaaa".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding your regex with `[]` is wrong, since all the content inside is interpreted as part of a character class. In your case:

```
[(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}]
```

It is a character class containing `A-Z`, `0-9`, `a-z`, `{}()?=.,*`.

Since `NSRegularExpression` is using ICU's regex library, it supports character class union, like in Java.

The correct regex should be:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$
```

Your first piece of code with `NSRegularExpression` should be:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                 regularExpressionWithPattern:
                                     @"^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$"
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                    options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

BOOL status = numberOfMatches == 1;
```

Since the regex only matches when it matches the whole string, you will get at most 1 match.

Your second piece of code with `NSPredicate` should be:

```
NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"SELF MATCHES %@",
                            @"'^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$'"];
BOOL status = [test evaluateWithObject:string];
```

Note that apart from the escaping of `\` which you have to do for the String object literal, you need to [take care of another level of escaping for the string literal in predicate syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9) (see the example). Luckily, we don't have to care about that here, since you don't use `\` in your regex.

The regex should not be specified directly in the format string (like in the previous revision), since it will incur another level of escaping for format string syntax.